# Excel iterate over rows and assign random date

Tags: excel

Is it possible to iterate my excel rows and in the date column, assign a random date, but within a data range?

```
Name    DOB       EntryDate
Name01  4/2/1984  4/2/2015 10:45
```

Comment: Yes this is possible, both with a formula solution and a VBA solution.  What are you looking for and what have you tried?

Comment: =RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1905,1,1),DATE(2000,1,30)) but I don't know how to include the time

Comment: @Rod: What time? A date of birth time? Your sample data does not show a time.

Comment: A time value is a decimal number between 0 and 1.  For example, 12:00 noon is .5 because it is halfway through the day.  If you want a random time, just tack this on to the end of your formula: `=formula+RAND()` and make sure to format the cell as date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    A              B         C
1   4/2/2014       4/2/2015  =Round(A1+RAND()*(B1-A1),0)
```

To keep dates form changing each time you recalcualte copy `C1` and paste Value( Ctrl+Alt+V)

Column `A` has the earliest date, and Column `B` has the Latest.